# Web apps without HTML or Javascript using WebAssembly and Dart?

Tags: dart

With the introduction of WebAssembly (https://webassembly.org/) it will be possible to run a web app in a web browser by using Dart without using Javascript and HTML at all?

Comment: This question is fairly broad and isn't really valid for StackOverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The general answer, however, is *no*. HTML and JavaScript are still currently required in order to use WebAssembly -- it is intended to supplement them, not replace them. Also, Dart does not run in web browsers at all; it has to be converted to Javascript via dart2js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely, for the same reasons I probably told you (or someone) in Gitter. WebAssembly apparently doesn't have the same access to the DOM that JavaScript can, and also has a different GC model.

Comment: Hi Randal Thank you for the answer again, I ask the question in several forums to gain more information.